# excel vba - copy formula and generate new sheets

Tags: vba, excel, scripting

if i have a sheet called 'values' with just 1 column with cells such as:

```
ColumnA
---------
emp_id
emp_name
dept_id
```

and then a 2nd sheet called 'sql' with 2 columns with cells such as:

```
ColumnA
--------
="select count(*) from tablex where "&a1&" is null;"
="select count(*) from tablex where length("&a1&") > 10;"

ColumnB
--------
Sheet for null
Sheet for length
```

What VBA macro code (note i need it in vba as i just want to click one button to generate the sheets) would i need to generate the following two output sheets (each sheet with just one column):

```
    Sheet for null
-------------------
select count(*) from tablex where emp_id is null;
select count(*) from tablex where emp_name is null;
select count(*) from tablex where dept_id is null;


    Sheet for length
-------------------
select count(*) from tablex where length(emp_id) > 10;
select count(*) from tablex where length(emp_name) > 10;
select count(*) from tablex where length(dept_id) > 10;
```

Comment: which database do you connect to? (where is `tablex`). What have you already tried?

Comment: Oracle. Just to get this simple example working tablex is hardcoded but in future i would put the tablename in a cell next to each fieldname.  i've tried it just manually copying down cells but i would really like to save time with vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you are asking.

One change I made is that on the "sql" sheet, I changed the cell contents to look like this:

```
="select count(*) from tablex where variable is null;"
```

so I used "**variable**" instead of "**&a1&**" like you originally had, and then in the code it replaces this word with the correct value of emp_id, emp_name, etc.

```
    Sub GenerateSheets()
    Dim formulaRange As Range
    Dim formula As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim destloc As Range
    Dim VariableRange As Range

    Set formulaRange = Worksheets("sql").Cells(1, 1)
    ' get each formula
    Do Until formulaRange.Value = ""
        For Each r In formulaRange.Rows
            ' for each formula found, create a new sheet and move it to end
            Worksheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Name = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
            ActiveSheet.Move after:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

            Set destloc = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
            Set VariableRange = Worksheets("values").Cells(1.1)
            ' Loop through all the variables
            Do Until VariableRange.Value = ""
                destloc.Value = Replace(formulaRange.Value, "variable", VariableRange.Value)

                Set VariableRange = VariableRange.Offset(1, 0)
                Set destloc = destloc.Offset(1, 0)
            Loop
        Next

        Set formulaRange = formulaRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop 
End Sub
```